# Magento Images are rotating when uploaded

Tags: image, magento, image-uploading

This only happens on the product pages with images with a larger height than 500px approximately. Caching is disabled. Products display correctly at smaller sizes but i need a solution that doesn't require image resizing before uploading.

I believe its something to do with using multiple image resizer program and some of the meta information in the image.

Thanks

Comment: Would it be cheating to suggest that you flip them before you upload them so when uploaded they flip the correct way up? :D

Comment: These images are used in several places so better there all the same and have only one version.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It sounds like there is EXIF data in the jpeg which records which way 'up' is. Either this info is getting ignored when you upload but is not ignored on your PC - explaining why the image looks the right way up when you view it on your desktop, but the wrong way up in Magento, or vice versa.

Can you use an art program or bulk convertor like XnView to either apply or remove the EXIF data before uploading? Then you might need to manually rotate some images.

Comment: Windows 8 puts a flag on images if there rotated which some programs don't recognise thats what happened in my case. Thanks

Comment: @Malachy : Could you pls explain briefly?